# How can i configure Log4j to generate new log file every time the java application runs

Tags: log4j, appender

How can I configure Log4j to generate new log file every time the java application runs?
I want the log name to vary every time like `[Log file name]_[CurrentTime].log`
I am using `.property` file to configure log4j

i am using  RollingFileAppender but this did not worked for me.here is my configuration

```
log4j.appender.dest4=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest4.File=.\\\\log4j\\\\user.log
log4j.appender.dest4.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest4.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}] : %-5p: %m%n
log4j.appender.dest4.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html)

Here´s an interesting post about the subject which applies to **log4j** as well: [How do I configure a RollingFileAppender to roll by date and size with log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243572/how-do-i-configure-a-rollingfileappender-to-roll-by-date-and-size-with-log4net)

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I am not wrong rolling file appended only rolls the log file to create new log file. All this time the application will be running. I want a new log file every time I run the application preferable appending date and time at the end of the file name. Its like keeping a session record each time the application runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html) dynamically

SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout,"logname."+new Date().toLocaleString(),false);
logger.addAppender(appender);