# log4j rolling RollingFileAppender doesn't working

Tags: java, log4j

I have log4j.xml for my app. The configuration is:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender> 

<appender name="app" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
 <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/var/log/folder/myApp_new.log.%d{yyyy-MM}.gz"/>
    </rollingPolicy>
        <param name="File" value="/var/log/folder/myApp_new.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100kB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

When I added org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender the application stopped logging. The problem is in rolling. I need use org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender because I would like have every day new log and every log have to 10MB.
Thank you.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683364/how-to-configure-log4j-to-only-keep-log-files-for-the-last-seven-days) helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/243608/6722100

Comment: @notyou Thank you, but I need divide logs on more files, when file have greater size than 10MB. The result should be myApp_new.2018-06-08.log.1
This example divided only on time.