# How to get log4net to keep only the last X days of logs?

Tags: .net, configuration, log4net

I only want log4net to keep let's say 10 days-worth of log files as keeping them growing indefinitely will eventually eat up my disk space.  I had thought that I could do this by setting

```
<maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
```

on my RollingFileAppender but no dice.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date) for answers.

Make sure you are not rolling the logs by Date as per [the SDK](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender.htm):

> A maximum number of backup files when
>   rolling on date/time boundaries is not
>   supported.

Comment: Thanks, though I don't necessarily need date/time boundaries, file number boundaries or total size boundaries will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is what exactly I am looking for.

Maybe this will help?

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value="logfile" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<rollingStyle value="Composite" />
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're saying - what part of this exactly limits to the last 10 days? The other answer (which admittedly is old) seems to imply that it is not possible

Comment: This will keep 10 files per day, not 10 files total

Comment: This will keep 10 files per day, not 10 files total