# Do you know of a log4net appender which rolls on date, but let's you limit the total number of files?

Tags: .net, log4net, rollingfileappender

I need to define an appender for log4net in a way that I get one log file for each day, but the total number of files are limited to, let's say, 30. That is I want to keep only the logs not older then 30 days, delete the older ones.

I've tried doing it with RollingFileAppender, but it seems that [specifying a limit of files to keep is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date). Do you know of an alternative solution that I could use?

Comment: how do you want to be limited? by suppression of ancient files? I don't see a principle of doing that...

Comment: I just want older files to be deleted. This is an application running on a mobile device with limited storage space. I don't care about old log files, but would like purging of them happen automatically.

Comment: log4net really creates new logs each day(for a rollingfileappender), but I doubt that it can(and should) delete it.

Comment: It actually deletes old files if you do rolling by size and set the maxSizeRollBackups to the limit of number of files. For some reason this property doesn't work with rolling by date, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time looking into this a few months ago. v1.2.10 doesn't support deleting older log files based on rolling by date. It is on the task list for the next release. I took the source code and added the functionality myself, and posted it for others if they are interested. The issue and the patch can be found at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-27 .

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at your patch. I've eventually also modified the appender myself (well, subclassed it to be exact), but I only needed to deal with rolling by date (not by date and size), so I didn't consider actually making it public.

Answer (score 1):

Write a C# WinService or make in your application a BackgroundWorker that will monitor once a day your old log files and delete it. You can use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) for this scope.

Or just test at each application running the presence of new log files and delete it.

An other option will be do not store files locally but send it via network (mail, distant server etc).

See also duplicate questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121932/how-to-get-log4net-to-keep-only-the-last-x-days-of-logs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date).

Answer (score 1):

can you use the 'Composite' log type? more here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

```
 <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value="logfile" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<rollingStyle value="Composite" />
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
<maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this will actually create a new file each day, then, if log exceeds 1MB it will create another log file with the same date and when the number of logs for this date exceeds 10 it will delete them. It will not limit the total number of logs, though (per date).