# How to create file without lock in c#

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, io

I'm creating text file at location using following code.

```
File.Create("C:\mylog.txt").Close();
```

But by default it is locked mode

I tried similar file to create using below code in unlock mode but i failed.

```
 var outStream = new FileStream("C:\mylog.txt", FileMode.Create,
   FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

> How do I create file in no lock mode?

Comment: "but I failed", how did you fail? How did you know? What happened? If you can tell us how you verified that it was created in/with a lock, perhaps we can give you a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create file without opening/locking it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116161/create-file-without-opening-locking-it)

Comment: You also have FileAccess set to Write only so no one can read from it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use the using statement

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Create(yourpath)) {
    // your code
}
```

When you create a file using `File.Create` then it returns the `FileStream` and opens the `FileStream` and hence your file is locked. When you use the `using` statement then the `FileStream` is closed automatically when you are done.