# Directory.GetFiles("*.pdf").count() show files, even if the directory is empty when using internet explorer

Tags: c#

I dont know whether this issue is faced by any one but i didn't get any solution on the net.

This is my code.

using zetalong path dll and also did with System.IO.File.Move(),

```
ZlpDirectoryInfo trackingdirectory = new ZlpDirectoryInfo(SourceWithTracking);

trackingdirectory.Refresh();

//If no file exist then delete direcory
if (trackingdirectory.GetFiles("*.pdf").Count() == 0)
{           
 ZlpIOHelper.DeleteDirectory(trackingdirectory.ToString(), true);
}
```

The files are getting deleted but when it checks for .GetFiles(*.pdf").count() system gives 11 files count even though the folder is empty.

I am facing this issue in Internet explorer 9,10 but it works with Firefox and chorme.

Comment: Side note: if whatever `GetFiles()` returns supports any form of `Any()` call, prefer that over `Count()` - it's generally a bad idea to force a system to produce a precise answer (and so have to potentially explore an entire data set) when all you care about is partitioning the world into "none exist" and "at least one exists".

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't found any hidden files? ([GetFiles](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths/blob/master/Source/Runtime/ZlpIOHelper.cs) returns an array apparently so it should support `Any`)

Comment: "**Note**  In rare cases or on a heavily loaded system, file attribute information on NTFS file systems may not be current at the time this function is called. To be assured of getting the current NTFS file system file attributes, call the `GetFileInformationByHandle` function." Found that snippet [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) because Zeta whatever is using `FindFirstFile` to retrieve the files.

Comment: Perhaps you could test this for us? The code in the [Zeta library](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths/blob/master/Source/Runtime/ZlpIOHelper.cs) is not very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

"The files are getting deleted",
"Directory.GetFiles shows files".

These both scream "file system tunneling" ([MSDN link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/15/439261.aspx)) to me.

I think you might need to post-process the result (e.g. create a new [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check the file actually exists).

Maybe use [Thread.Sleep(30000)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a test to maybe wait 30 seconds and see if the files still show up? If the files don't show up, it's probably tunneling.

If you **have** to, I guess you can keep a list of files you've deleted and ignore those in the returned `Directory.GetFiles` result.

Comment: but why this is working fine in Firefox and chrome and not in Interner explorer i didn't understand.

Comment: What about if before deleting a file, you rename it to something else (e.g. "_originalFileName.pdf")? @Joe suggests it in [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2109292/1364007).

Comment: I don't think this is tunneling. Tunneling is when he's recreating the files, and as far as I can tell, he's not. I think he needs to call `GetFileInformationByHandle` on the file handles returned from `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`.