# Logging Frameworks

Tags: logging, frameworks

For a .NET application , we need a Logging Framework. The main requirements are

1)Support different kinds of Logging levels - like Debug , Warn etc
2)A new log  file should be created , when the current file  exceeds a particular size
3)The back up log files should be deleted after a configured amount of time period like for ex: - 1 day

Are there any frameworks that satisy  3rd criteria

Regards
Sabarish

Answer (score 0):

Log4Net can do pretty much anything with custom appenders. Take a look here: [How I can set log4net to log my files into different folders each day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385669/how-i-can-set-log4net-to-log-my-files-into-different-folders-each-day/2385874#2385874) or here: [Can Log4Net Delete Log Files Automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259795/can-log4net-delete-log-files-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

[Serilog](http://serilog.net) provides this; e.g.

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile("C:\\Logs\\myapp-{Date}.txt",
        fileSizeLimitBytes: 123456,
        retainedFileCountLimit: 31)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Files are rolled each day, with the size limit being more of a "safety" feature than a rolling strategy, but the results should match pretty closely with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote somewhat simple but sufficient framework for logging myself being tired of overcomplication of log4net, nlog etc. https://github.com/aloneguid/logmagic