# RollingFileAppender doesn't roll over anymore after a couple of weeks

Tags: log4net, rollingfileappender

I'm using log4net (v1.2.9.0) in a web project. Everything works like a charm, but after a couple of weeks the `RollingFileAppender` stopped to roll over. Instead, every log message is appended to the same file which therefore has a giant size by now.

Here is my log4net configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\CAPServer\\log\\CWSServer.log"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
  <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="50"/>
    <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd"/>
    <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
 </appender>
 <root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
 </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to try from the documentation on http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html:

Try removing the entry for `MaxSizeRollBackups`.

> **CAUTION**
>   A maximum number of backup
>   files when rolling on date/time
>   boundaries is not supported.

Try clearing out the directory of all log files.

> **CAUTION**
>   Changing StaticLogFileName
>   or CountDirection without clearing the
>   log file directory of backup files
>   will cause unexpected and unwanted
>   side effects.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I was ill for a couple of days. But now I was able to test your recommendations but with no result. It still didn't roll over. I even tried to update to v1.2.10. Still the same behaviour.
Do you have any addtional ideas?