# Creating new Log file everyday and deleting previous log files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, logging, log4net

I have one windows service. For Logging purpose in that service I am using Log4Net.dll. Now my requirement is that I want to create a new log file everyday and it should keep the log of only previous 7 days. Means on 8th day, it should delete first day file and use new file. I am using appender as:

```xml
 <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\Log\%property{LogName}" />
     <AppendToFile value="true" />
     <rollingStyle value="Date" />      
     <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />       
     <staticLogFileName value="false" />
     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%newline %date %-5level %C.%M() - %message" />
     </layout>
 </appender>
```

And at service startup I am configuring logger as:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "App_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".log";
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

So is there any functionality of Log4Net that will achieve above functionality? Or is there any other way to do it? Any type of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't: [RollingFileAppender Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date)

> A maximum number of backup files when rolling on date/time boundaries
>   is not supported

Have a look at this thread for other suggestions: [Log4Net: set Max backup files on RollingFileAppender with rolling Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date)

To implement log file everyday you would use:

```
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
```