# How to configure Log4Net to Delete logs by date

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, log4net-filter

```
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
      <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm} %-5level %message%newline%exception" />
  </layout>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

maximum number of backup files when rolling on date/time 
  boundaries is not supporting.can anyone please me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log4Net: set Max backup files on RollingFileAppender with rolling Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date)

Comment: i tried but log files are not deleted when using rolling Style by date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

**CAUTION**

A maximum number of backup files when rolling on date/time boundaries is not supported.

For more Info see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97641/3665063)

Answer (score 1):

You can't out of the box, however you can implement your custom appender behavoir by inheriting the RollingFileAppender or SkeletonAppender.

Comment: could you please give example

Comment: As sample can you use: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Appender/RollingFileAppender.cs?view=markup

Comment: @Peter The link is dead.

Comment: They moved their code to github: https://github.com/apache/log4net/blob/trunk/src/Appender/RollingFileAppender.cs